# Swift3 Array convert in String like "{\"type\": \"0\"}"

Tags: arrays, string, swift3, parameter-passing

I have created one array in Swift. I have one node.js API, In this API only passing string type data like this

```
 let Dic = "{\"type\": \"0\",\"message\": \"\(message)\", \"sender_id\":\"\(username)\", \"reciever_id\": \"61\", \"\(username)\": \"2017-05-09 03:02:55 PM\"}"
```

I cant able to pass this **Dic** in API. But the problem is,  I have one array how can I convert an array to the string . I have to add one more parameter in **Dic** and then pass this array here is my code how I am generating this array

```
(
        {
        Desc = "This is suger for m23 type ";
        Price = 50;
        Product = "Suger temp";
    },
        {
        Desc = "This is suger for m23 type ";
        Price = 50;
        Product = "Suger temp";
    }
)
```

Code is

```
let ary_allPRoduct :NSMutableArray = []

            for i in 0..<count {
                var dict = Dictionary<String, Any>()
                dict["Product"]="Suger temp"
                dict["Desc"]="This is suger for m23 type "
                dict["Price"]="50"

                ary_allPRoduct.add(dict)

            }

            print(ary_allPRoduct)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, please apply this code.

```
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
print(jsonString)
```

NOTE: On console it'll normally print the string. But if you check it on Breakpoint. You'll see exact format you needed and it should work.

On Console: ({"nacho":["1","2","3"]})

And 
[How its should look on Breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxmpE.png)

Comment: `jsonString` can be created much shorter `let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)`. There is no need at all to use `NSString` in Swift and you can omit the `options` parameter in `data(withJSONObject`